# Code coverage and cyclomatic complexity

Tags: solidity, testing, dapple

Is there any way to find code coverage and cyclomatic complexity for test cases in dapple , similar to the tool we have in java which give every aspect of our code

Comment: Unfortunately, I think not. It would be great is someone would build a code-coverage tool, though

Comment: @ryepdx , could you please comment on this one , as you were involved in development of dapple

Answer (score 2):

Not Dapple, unfortunately, but there's now a Truffle-related code coverage tool available called [SolCover](https://github.com/JoinColony/solcover).

There's a description of its implementation and features in a related [article](https://blog.colony.io/code-coverage-for-solidity-eecfa88668c2#.w72gdj1yx).